# Animation based upon TableView ContentOffset.Y

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, animatewithduration

I'm having some problems with scrollview within TableView to animate correctly. I want the element with the constraints to animate off-screen when dragging down (this doesn't work), and then when let go it springs back to position (this part works):

```
private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
            resetConstraints()
        }
    else if lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 20, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.rightStatsConstraint.priority = 1
            self.offscreenRightStatsConstraint.priority = 999
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    // update the new position acquired
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

}
```

Basically when the scrollview stops, it properly animates back to position (for resetConstraints) but the original animation (offscreenRightStatsConstraint) gets called and jumps off screen but with no animation. Any reason for this?

```
    func resetConstraints() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 20, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        lastContentOffset = 0
        self.rightStatsConstraint.priority = 999
        self.offscreenRightStatsConstraint.priority = 1
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "original animation (offscreenRightStatsConstraint)"?

Comment: You mean the animation that moves the view off screen when you swipe down on the table view?

Comment: Yeah, this basically moves the element (stackView in this case) off the screen. rightStatsConstraint has a -80 offset from the trailing edge of the backgroundView (so it stays in place) and offscreenRightStatsConstraint has a 100 offset from the trailing edge of the backgroundView so it should fly off the screen. I'm changing the priority so that there is limited performance effect, but the initial movement off screen using the "if lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y" does not produce an animation.

Comment: I copied your code. Seems to animate for me. Have your tied turing slow animation on? command-t in the simulator.

Comment: You're right, it does seem to animate in slow-mo. However it doesn't show that it does on my device nor the simulator. It just disappears. Never new that that function existed so thanks. I guess I'll have to fiddle around and slow down the velocity to see if that helps.

Comment: Right your animation is too fast. Play around with it.